# React onClick event not firing with express-react-views

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I am using `express-react-views` + `NodeJS` to make a media platform. My "like button" element is not firing it's `onClick` event. My relevant code:

```
<h1>{this.state.title}</h1> 103 <button onClick = {this.like}></button>
```

```js
this.like = async (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   await axios({ method: "GET", url: "http://localhost:9037/test" });
};
```

> Note: I don't need to *get* the data of the request.

What can I do to get it to work?

Comment: Could you try using an arrow function onClick={() => this.like()}

Comment: @DiegoBascans I tried, but it's not working.

Comment: Maybe you can add a console.log inside the like method to check if you are accessing on the click event.

Comment: @DiegoBascans I tried that. I put a console.log in the route for /test as well as the event itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express-react-views` is static server-side capability. To call react code you have to include react client side.

See this issue about this behavior https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views/issues/59

This example might do what you want https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views/tree/master/examples/dynamic