# React onclick event not working on repl.it

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a server side react project on the site called [Repl it](https://replit.com/). However, the onClick event does not work on the site. What am I doing wrong, is it the site's fault?

Code: https://replit.com/@kodkaw/UrbanUnfortunateCoding#views/index.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link maybe It's help you

[React onClick event not firing with express-react-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187089/react-onclick-event-not-firing-with-express-react-views)

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't changed

Comment: `express-react-views` renders static markup, so handlers don't work.

Comment: @user4980215 How can I fix

Comment: please checkout It may help you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187089/react-onclick-event-not-firing-with-express-react-views

Comment: @DevendraKushwaha how can i do this in repl it. do you have an example